# Encode rows of boolean numpy array to bytes

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of dimensions Nx8, with dtyp=boolean
I want to convert it into a numpy 1-d array where each row is turned into a byte, by bin2dec

```
x = array([[ True,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ False,  False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  False, False, False,  False,  False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

I'd like the output to be:

```
y = array([204 ,12, 128], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Im trying to encode each line into an integer

Comment: but whats up with the dimensions? (and how big is N going to be?)

Comment: what is the question exactly? X is a 3x8 array, i want to turn each line of 8 booleans into a single int, so the output would be a 1-d array of length 3 and dtype int8.
N is potentially quite large, can be 10,000-20,000

Comment: So where does the 204 come from?

Comment: @ecatmur see my answer, he actually means uint8 instead of int8

Comment: This is actually an excellent question. I'm not sure why you're getting downvoted (other than mistyping `int8` instead of `uint8`).

Comment: @eran Does my solution give you what you want? (i edited it a bit so it is easier for you to go to whatever size you want to make it (20k or so))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> np.packbits(np.uint8(x))
array([204,  12, 128], dtype=uint8)
```

How that?

Comment: I'd go with `x.view(np.uint8)`, because I know for sure it doesn't copy any data. Other than that, +1.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will do:

```
import numpy
x = numpy.array([[ True,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ False,  False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  False, False, False,  False,  False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
x2 = 1*x # makes True become 1 and False become 0
x3 = numpy.zeros((3), dtype = numpy.uint8) # change 3 to 20000 or whatever the length of your array is
for j in range(x2.shape[1]):
    x3 += x2[:,j]*(2**(7-j))
print x3
[204  12 128]
```

Tell me how long it takes for your long array, if it goes too slow, i will try to push the for-loop down to numpy to speed it up.  (needs to be uint8 instead of int8, otherwise the result is [ -52   12 -128])

edit: should actually not be that slow, since the for-loop only runs 8 times (once per float)